# C++/CLI не находит библиотеку DLL, основанной на C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

В общем, написал я следующий код в CLI_out на C# (.NET 4.6) и скомпилировал его в CLR_out.dll

```c
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CLR_out
{
    public class CLR_out_class
    {
        public static string outProc(int n, String input)
        {

            StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(input);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                tmp.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", " ", tmp.ToString());
            return tmp.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

И попытался его вызвать на С++/CLI здесь.

```c
#include <iostream>

#using <CLR_out.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace CLR_out;

int main()
{
    String ^ s = gcnew String("QWERTY");
    CLR_out_class ^ CLR = gcnew CLR_out_class;
    String ^ tmp = CLR->outProc(8, s);
    char * out = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(tmp);
    std::cout << out;
}
```

И в результате, программа не находит библиотеку:
[image: FileNotFound]
Вопрос:
Как сделать так, чтобы приложение на С++ смогло найти библиотеку на C# (.NET)?

Comment: Соберите платформой зависимую библиотеку, а не AnyCpu, и подключите снова.

Comment: И в CLR_in, и в CLR_out стоят x86, Debug. Для CLR_out платформу пришлось создать, ничего?